# support actionbar menu styling

Tags: android, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

How does one style the Android ActionBar overflow menu (background color, text color, custom drawables etc.)?

I've been trying to do this with the following styles, but nothing seems to be taking any effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<resources>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        </style>

        <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
            <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
            <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

TIA!

BTW minSdk set to 14

AndroidManifest is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app1.app1">

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call it on AndroidManifest.xml file?
Example in my style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green_dark</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

and in menifestfile

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <activity.....
```

For implement click listener, you need create option menu for this case.

Comment: Yes it is set in my manifest application theme but weirdly does not seem to have any effect.